# R CMD check fails with ubuntu when trying to download file, but function works within R

Tags: r, ssl, testing, github-actions, devtools

I am writing an R package and one of its functions download and unzips a file from a link (it is not exported to the user, though):

```
download_f <- function(download_dir) {
  utils::download.file(
    url = "https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php",
    destfile = file.path(download_dir, "fines.rar"),
    mode = 'wb',
    method = 'libcurl'
  )

  utils::unzip(
    zipfile = file.path(download_dir, "fines.rar"),
    exdir = file.path(download_dir)
  )
}
```

This function works fine with me when I run it within some other function to compile an example in a vignette.

However, with R CMD check in github action, it fails consistently on ubuntu 16.04, release and devel. It [says][1]:

```
Error: Error: processing vignette 'IBAMA.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
cannot open URL 'https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php'
--- failed re-building ‘IBAMA.Rmd’

SUMMARY: processing the following file failed:
  ‘IBAMA.Rmd’

Error: Error: Vignette re-building failed.
Execution halted
Error: Error in proc$get_built_file() : Build process failed
Calls: <Anonymous> ... build_package -> with_envvar -> force -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

When I run `devtools::check()` it never finishes running it, staying in "creating vignettes" forever. I don't know if these problems are related though because there are other vignettes on the package.

I pass the R CMD checks with mac os and windows. I've tried switching the "mode" and "method" arguments on `utils::download.file`, but to no avail.

Any suggestions?
[1]: https://github.com/datazoompuc/datazoom.amazonia/pull/16/checks?check_run_id=2026865974

Comment: Might be a [firewall problem](https://github.community/t/what-is-the-default-firewall-for-github-actions-runners/17732)

Comment: But whose firewall? I dont understand how does github action works, because my Server is Windows....

Comment: My understanding is that github action runs the checks on its own servers, but I never used it : hopefully someone with experience on the subject can help

Comment: I can reproduce this issue on my local Ubuntu 18.04 machine. It could be similar to an issue I once had: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559526/downloading-from-a-public-server-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-i - and I got a truly excellent answer. In that case the issue would not be on your site, but a wrong configuration of the download server.

Comment: @nevrome thank you! Do you have any idea on how to avoid this error being a Windows user? I don't actually know what to change based on your link, since it is github's internal servers that are using Linux and failing the test

Comment: If this issue is indeed identical to mine, then you should write to the admins of https://servicos.ibama.gov.br and inform them about the issue. If you need a solution NOW and can not wait for them to react, then you can attempt a hack as the one suggested in the second answer to my question. You would have to add some code to your github action to manually install the intermediate certificate. This would make the checks pass, but of course some users of your package may experience the issue anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download fails because libcurl tries to verify the webservers certificate, but can't.

I can reproduce this on my system:

```
trying URL 'https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php'
Error in utils::download.file(url = "https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php",  : 
  cannot open URL 'https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php'
In addition: Warning message:
In utils::download.file(url = "https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php",  :
  URL 'https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php': status was 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'
```

The server does not allow you to download from http but redirects to https, so the only thing to do now is to tell libcurl to not check the certificate and accept what it is getting.

You can do this by specifying the argument `-k` to `curl`

```
download_f <- function(download_dir) {
  utils::download.file(
    url = "https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php",
    destfile = file.path(download_dir, "fines.rar"),
    mode = 'wb',
    method = 'curl',
    extra = '-k'
  ) 
  
  utils::unzip(
    zipfile = file.path(download_dir, "fines.rar"),
    exdir = file.path(download_dir)
  ) 
}
```

This also produces some download progress bar, you can silence this by setting extra to `-k -s`

This now opens you up to a Machine In The Middle Attack. (You possibly already are attacked this way, there is no way to check without verifying the current certificate with someone you know at the other side)
So you could implement an extra check, e.g. **check the sha256sum of the downloaded file** and see if it matches what you expect to receive before proceeding.

```
myfile <- system.file("fines.rar")
hash <- sha256(file(myfile))
```